# .net 7 CORS error on posting file upload to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

The problem as been solved:

> I found a problem and finally I fixed it! That's because I dont
> set permissions for www-data user in ubuntu. just run "sudo chown -R
> www-data /var/www/abc.vn/wwwroot/uploads" and with the upload api I
> wrote above, it works!

---

I got a CORS error when trying to upload FormData to Controller. But the problem is it could run very well on localhost but on the server is no.

> Access to fetch at 'http://api.abc.vn/OnPostUpload' from origin
> 'http://central.abc.vn' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My localhost: Windows and IIS

My Server: Ubuntu 22 and Nginx

This is the javascript using fetch to send data:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('FileDetails', e.target.files[0]);
formData.append('FileName', e.target.files[0].name);
formData.append('TenantId', localStorage.getItem('TenantId'));
fetch(API_URL + 'OnPostUpload',
{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'TenantId': localStorage.getItem('TenantId'),
        'Token': localStorage.getItem("Token")
    },
    body: formData
})
```

This is my Upload api:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/OnPostUpload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync([FromForm] FileUploadModel data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return new JsonResult(false);
            }

            if (data != null)
            {
                string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"wwwroot/uploads/" + data.TenantId + "/"));
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(data.FileName);
                var absolutePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

                var appfile = await _repository.AddAsync(new AppFile()
                {
                    FileName = data.FileName,
                    Path = absolutePath,
                    TenantId = data.TenantId,
                });
                await _repository.SaveChangesAsync();

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(absolutePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await data.FileDetails.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                return new JsonResult(new { Path = "uploads/" + data.TenantId + "/" + fileName, AppFileId = appfile.Id });
            }
            return new JsonResult(false);
        }
```

FileUploadModel.cs

```
public class FileUploadModel
    {
        public IFormFile FileDetails { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
    }
```

**What I have tried?**

- I have increased file upload size to 100M but still no hope
- I have setup cors like this in Programs.cs but as I said, it only work in localhost, not work in Ubuntu Nginx server

  builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
  {
  options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder =>
  {
  builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44460",
  "http://central.abc.vn",
  "http://demo.abc.vn")
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowAnyMethod()
  .AllowCredentials();
  });
  });
- I have tried add [EnableCors] attribute on top of API but still not working

And thanks for spending your time to read my post. Hope to hear your solution

Comment: You need an Admin with CORS privilege on Network to solve issue.

Comment: What *exactly* does the error tell you?

Comment: @David Hi, the error is "Access to fetch at 'http://api.abc.vn/OnPostUpload' from origin 'http://central.abc.vn' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: @jdweng can you give me more detail so I can try? I have never heard about this before

Comment: Hi Ryan, please check the folder `uploads` exist or not in your ubuntu server.

Comment: @JasonPan yes, I am sure that it exist

Comment: Could you share the Program.cs file and hide the sensitive info,tks

Comment: Because I need to check the middleware you used and how you increased file upload size to 100M.

Comment: @JasonPan I use Nginx, and I increased file upload size by edit nginx.conf . Here is my program.cs https://codeshare.io/eVE1Kb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255185/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-ryan-can-fly).

Comment: The CORS policy on a Network is set by the admin of the network.  So CORS can be blocked and you may not be able to unblock.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the complete cross-domain configuration, if I guess well, maybe you are missing `app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName)`

Sample code

```
const string DefaultCorsPolicyName = "ApiCORS";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName,
    builder =>
    {
        builder
        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44460", "http://central.abc.vn", "http://demo.abc.vn")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

.....

// This should be above the UseStaticFiles();
// Typically, UseStaticFiles is called before UseCors. Apps that use JavaScript to retrieve static files cross site must call UseCors before UseStaticFiles.
app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName);
```

If you want to go deeper, read the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usecors-and-usestaticfiles-order)

Comment: Thanks @vchy, my program.cs already had app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName); I tried change position as you mentioned but still no luck

Comment: Hi,@Ryancanfly
Sorry for not helping you solve the problem
I try to deploy to centos test is normal, don't know if you have solved it？
If you haven't solved it, can you provide a mini example git?

Comment: do you use Nginx server?

Comment: I still not solve it, I dont know where is the probem. Did your upload api the same as mine?

Comment: I'm thinking that the problem is my upload function, can you give me your example?

Comment: Of course, please wait a few minutes, I need to add git

Comment: @Ryancanfly hi，please check the git 
https://github.com/vchy1997/SampleCors.git

Comment: I found a problem, when the file is too large, `CORS` error will also appear, but I originally tested because I used a relatively small image, I think you can try small files first

Comment: I found a problem too and finally I fixed it! That's because I dont set permissions for www-data user in ubuntu. just run 
"sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/abc.vn/wwwroot/uploads" and with the upload api I wrote above, it works!

Comment: Ok, I learned something new. Thanks